# How can i select the div from CSS?

Tags: css

I want to select the div of following order:

```
div3,div4
div7,div8
div11,div12
div15,div16
and so on....
```

I was wondering, how can i achieve this order by nth child property of CSS?
Please help!!!

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Do you have classes on these div's? Also can we change your HTML structure to make it work better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing your structure it's hard to be definitive but the `nth-of-type` selectors can help here.

```
div:nth-of-type(4n+3) {  /* every 4th div starting at 3 */
  background: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(4n+4) {  /* every 4th div starting at 4 */
  background:blue;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/s1y09s3e/)

Comment: Just establish a base styling and it will apply to the rest automatically - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/3suyy9cu/

Answer (score 4):

Use following:

```
div:nth-child(4n-1){} /* for 3,7,11,15... */

div:nth-child(4n){} /* for 4,8,12,16... */
```

Snippet Below:

```css
div:nth-child(4n-1){
    background: red;
}
div:nth-child(4n){
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
```

Comment: Nice..I hadn't considered doing it that way.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS,

```
div:nth-child(4n+3),
div:nth-child(4n+4){
   /*do something*/
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the "n" variable have to go first? As in "(4n+3)", not "(3+4n)". Also you're combining both selectors into one style list, not separating them. I didn't downvote you btw